# Button to an external link or styling a link tag to look like a button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, link-to

I'm a newbie to RoR, but I'm looking to create a button that takes users to an external URL.

I've had trouble using link_to, because I haven't been able to style the hyperlink look like a button.

Then, I am able to get the button to appear with the following code:

```
%a#about-join-our-team.button Current Open Positions
```

But I can't add a URL to it in this format. (Button text = "Current Open Positions")

I'm sure I'm making some silly RoR mistake, but I just can't find the right answer in previous threads.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROR actually has a built-in helper called [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which does exactly what you need:

```
= button_to "Current Open Positions", your_url_path, class: "class"
```

This basically creates a small form, which Rails uses to send a request to. The user sees a [standard HTML button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_test)

Answer (score 0):

Following should work(HAML)

```
%a#about-join-our-team.button{href: your_url} Current Open Positions
```

(erb)

```
<a class="button" href="<%= your_url %>" id="about-join-our-team">Current Open Positions</a>
```